# Shape animation not working in Firefox but does in Chrome

Tags: css, animation

I am trying to animate from one shape to another. This works in Chrome, but not in the latest Firefox or IE.   On the following link hover over the yellow box to see the animation: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jH245/)

```
.element {   
    background-color: #f1c40f; 
    color: white;
    width: 500px; 
    height: 500px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    text-align: justify;
    shape-inside: polygon(250px 0, 350px 170px, 500px 180px, 380px 320px, 450px 500px, 250px 420px, 50px 500px, 120px 320px, 0px 180px, 150px 170px );
    shape-padding: 10px;
    transition: all 3s ease; 
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(250px 0, 350px 170px, 500px 180px, 380px 320px, 450px     500px, 250px 420px, 50px 500px, 120px 320px, 0px 180px, 150px 170px );
} 
.element:hover{ 
    shape-inside: polygon(250px 0, 500px 0, 500px 180px, 500px 320px, 500px 500px, 250px 500px, 0 500px, 0 320px, 0 180px, 0 0);
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(250px 0, 500px 0, 500px 180px, 500px 320px, 500px 500px,     250px 500px, 0 500px, 0 320px, 0 180px, 0 0);
}
```

Any suggestions on how to get this working cross-browser?

Thank you.

Comment: I was able to accomplish the effect I was looking for using CSS3 transform, transform-origin and transition